# Set parameter in sql, query not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this code here:

```
DECLARE @inputform varchar
SET @inputform = 'J61807017B'

SELECT * FROM test where text1 LIKE '@inputform'
```

This won't give me the desired output, but when i do like this it works:

```
DECLARE @inputform varchar
SET @inputform = 'J61807017B'

SELECT * FROM test where text1 LIKE 'J61807017B'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried without the surrounding single quotes ?  `SELECT * FROM test where text1 LIKE @inputform`

Comment: @ccheneson, yes and still nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the variable and drop the quotes when you use it:

```
DECLARE @inputform varchar(20)
SET @inputform = 'J61807017B'

SELECT * FROM test where text1 = @inputform
-- or text1 like '%'+ @inputform +'%' if you want to do partial matching
```

If you don't specify the size for a char/varchar value the size will be 1.

From the manual:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.